# Как декодировать JSON в данной ситуации?

Tags: php

Работаю в Joomla, при запросе `<?php echo '<pre>', print_r($this->item->extrafields['holyshit'], true), '</pre>';?>` получаю фрагмент, который приложен во фрагменте ниже.
Необходимо получить при запросе `<img src="<?php echo $this->item->extrafields['holyshit']->rawvalue; ?>">` красивое значение `src=""`, но при текущем выводится `<img src="/{" holyshit0":{"holyshit":"images\="" logo.png"}}"="">`
Как получить красивый `src=""`?

```html
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 8
    [title] => holyshit
    [name] => holyshit
    [checked_out] => 0
    [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [note] => 
    [state] => 1
    [access] => 1
    [created_time] => 2020-04-02 14:56:03
    [created_user_id] => 923
    [ordering] => 0
    [language] => *
    [fieldparams] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
        (
            [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [fields] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [fields0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [fieldname] => holyshit
                                    [fieldtype] => media
                                    [fieldfilter] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

            [initialized:protected] => 1
            [separator] => .
        )

    [params] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
        (
            [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [hint] => 
                    [class] => 
                    [label_class] => 
                    [show_on] => 
                    [render_class] => 
                    [showlabel] => 0
                    [label_render_class] => 
                    [display] => 0
                    [layout] => 
                    [display_readonly] => 2
                )

            [initialized:protected] => 1
            [separator] => .
        )

    [type] => repeatable
    [default_value] => 
    [context] => com_content.article
    [group_id] => 0
    [label] => holyshit
    [description] => 
    [required] => 0
    [language_title] => 
    [language_image] => 
    [editor] => 
    [access_level] => Public
    [author_name] => Super User
    [group_title] => 
    [group_access] => 
    [group_state] => 
    [group_note] => 
    [value] => 
images/logo.png

    [rawvalue] => {"holyshit0":{"holyshit":"images\/logo.png"}}
)
```

Comment: А зачем вы запрашиваете `rawvalue` ? Когда можно запросить просто `value`, в котором записано `images/logo.png`

Comment: @ArchDemon в данной ситуации возвращается не просто адрес, а примерно такое значение "<ul><li>/images/logo.png</li></ul>"

Comment: ну и скжите на него strip_tags()